# How often is a torus in a compact Lie group nullhomologous?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

**Minor nomenclature question**:

What is the standard name for the ring structure induced on the homology of an H-space by its multiplication? I've seen "homology ring" and "Pontrjagin ring."

**Hopefully deeper questions**:

In [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970463) (on pp.  1117 & 1134), Samelson states (as best I can understand through Google Translate) that

if a connected subgroup $U$ of a compact Lie group $G$ is not nullhomologous, then

1. the inclusion $U \hookrightarrow G$ induces an injection in rational homology, and
2. the rational homology rings of $G$ and the product manifold $U \times (G/U)$ are isomorphic.

It occurs to me that one could use this to understand the (co)homology of homogeneous spaces $G/U$ (or alternately, assuming one knows something about homogeneous spaces, to understand the homology of $G$ in terms of homogeneous spaces and tori). **How feasible is this strategy?**

**When are subgroups nullhomologous?** I've never really thought of that before. I'm especially concerned about tori. My thinking is that the cohomology ring of a compact Lie group is an exterior algebra; by Poincaré duality, I would expect tori to generally be nullhomologous, then, because $\dim H_1(G)$ will tend to be too small to support large tori. **Is that right?**

Are there illuminating examples? How should I think about this?

Comment: hey Jeff!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The story is this: any compact, connected Lie group $G$ admits a finite, central cover of the form $\tilde G = A \times K$ for $A$ a torus and $K$ a simply-connected Lie group (hence a product of simply-connected simple Lie groups). This can be expressed in the form of a short exact sequence which is also a fiber bundle, 
$$0 \to F \to A \times K \to G \to 1.$$

Note that $H_1 = \pi_1$ on groups, so that $\pi_1 S \to \pi_1 G$ is assumed injective. Applying the long exact sequence of a bundle to the display, one finds $\pi_1 A \cong \pi_1 A \times \pi_1 K$ is a finite-index subgroup of $\pi_1 G$. It follows that the preimage in $\pi_1 S$ of the image of $\pi_1 A \to \pi_1 G$ is of finite index. Take a finite connected cover $\tilde S \to S$ such that the image of $\pi_1 \tilde S$ lies in the image of $\pi_1 A$; then one can lift $S \to G$ to a map $\tilde S \to \tilde G$ which must again be a homomorphism, and the map it induces in $\pi_1$ is injective.

The homotopy behavior of this map
$$\tilde S \to A \times K$$
is determined by the component homomorphism $\tilde S \to A$ since $K$ is simply-connected, and this map is recoverable from $\pi_1(A \to S)$ by the observation that $\pi_1$ and $- \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb R$ are inverse equivalences between the categories of finite-dimensional tori and finitely-generated free abelian groups.

In case the group $U$ is not a torus, the question is a bit more complex, effectively breaking down into separate questions for semisimple and toroidal components of (some cover of) $U$, and the interesting part is when an inclusion $K \hookrightarrow G$ of simple Lie groups induces a surjection in cohomology. I am not aware where to find a complete answer to this question, although I'm sure it's settled at least modulo torsion. A series of examples appears in the third volume of Greub, Halperin, and Vanstone's tome, around p. 474.

Comment: What does $S$ denote?

Comment: Good question! It seems to be just any torus contained in $G$, whereas I guess $U$ is an arbitrary connected subgroup.